# How can we test kinvey-flex-sdk's locally?

Tags: kinvey, service-object

As per my understanding, the service-objects that we are registering are invoked by kinvey collections only. Is there any way to test that locally ?

I have written  below code.

var sdk = require('kinvey-flex-sdk');

const PORT = 8080;

sdk.service({ host: 'localhost', port: PORT }, function (err, flex) {

```
 const data = flex.data; 

 function authentication(request, complete, modules) {
       console.log("Inside...");
       complete().setBody("Authenticated");
 };

const widgets = data.serviceObject('widgets');

widgets.onInsert(authentication);
```

});

And my doubt is authentication function is not triggered for the POST request http://localhost:8080/widgets  {}..

Can u please help me in resolving that ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can run the service locally by just running "node index.js". It'll start a listener you can approach with e.g. Postman. Each local test requires a "POST" to a certain routes. Testing routes are documented here: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/flex-services#installation

Also see http://devcenter.kinvey.com/guides/flex-services#testing-locally
for the necessary headers you need to set on each request to get the correct context and permission

Comment: thanks for the commnet. I have added my code to the question. can u please take a look and help me if possible ?

Comment: What are the specific headers and postbody you are using? When I run your code, I do get the "Inside" log line. But the code doesn't complete because the completion handler is not fully correct. You must always end with complete.<statuscode> and complete.<action>. In your case, you can do:  "complete.setBody({some json here}).ok().done()".  Also, one typcially returns js-objects (translated to json) in the setBody, not just a string.

Comment: I am using "Content-Type" as "application/json" and "x-auth-key" as "kinveyTest" in Postman Headers. Do i need to add some other header for testing locally ? And i am hitting with "http://localhost:8080/:widgets/" (POST method)

Comment: You must always end with complete.<statuscode> and complete.<action>. In your case, you can do: "complete.setBody({some json here}).ok().done()". You are forgetting the ok and done parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass following headers :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Basic <basicAuth>
X-Kinvey-App-Metadata:{ "_id" : "<kinveyAppId>", "appsecret" : "<kinveyAppSecret>", "mastersecret" : "<kinveyMasterSecret>", "baasUrl" : "<kinveyBaseURL>" }
X-Kinvey-Original-Request-Headers:{ "x-kinvey-api-version" : "<KinveyApiVersion>", "authorization" : "Basic <basicAuth>", "x-kinvey-client-app-version" : "<KinveyClientAppVersion>"}
X-Kinvey-Username:<username>
X-Kinvey-User-Id:<userid>
```

If you're working with flex function :

```
http://localhost:<port>/_flexFunctions/<flexFunctionName>
```

Comment: Is it possible to test without kinvey configurations (testing locally) ?

Comment: you've install kinvey sdk & pass above headers, i'm also testing locally